Mapping functions in GBQ-pandas
I ran into a problem trying to map a basic function in GBQ.
Code:
def lengthen(text):
    return text+' - Esq.'

s = bf.Series(['James', 'John', 'Sally', ])
s.map(lengthen)

Result:

ValueError: A vectorized non-remote function can be provided only with by_row=False. For element-wise operation it must be a remote function.

Adding the by_row argument did not work.
s.map(lengthen, by_row=False)


TypeError: Series.map() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by_row'


In this instance it might help to see more of the story.  Perhaps create a document/PDF/assets where others can try and recreate the story you are describing.  For example, in your supplied code ... what is "bf"?  How does the code you show relate to Google's BigQuery?
